# React-router-dom v6. Navigate through products

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hope someone can help me here.
Been trying different things but always end up just extending my routes.
What i want is to be able to navigate through products (its some kinda eshop)

So, when i am in 1st product with prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD as product id

```
http://localhost:3000/combo/prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD
```

I need to be able to go to the next product (go back and forth as I have 3 buttons called "Prev" and "Next"). 6 products in total.
That's the array of product ids =

```
['prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD', 'prod_RyWOwmPkL9lnEa', 'prod_ypbroE9QBno8n4', 'prod_Kvg9l61rEm51bB', 'prod_NqKE50NEPBwdgB', 'prod_kpnNwA1P8awmXB']
```

Once i reach the last product (prod_kpnNwA1P8awmXB) i need to go the first product.

In other words - just need to change product_id - last element of the route.

I think there is a good solution for this cos its a very common case. But I am unable to find.

Thanks!

Comment: Circular list structure would help you here or manually set last next to first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const comboproductsids = [
  'prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD',
  'prod_RyWOwmPkL9lnEa',
  'prod_ypbroE9QBno8n4',
  'prod_Kvg9l61rEm51bB',
  'prod_NqKE50NEPBwdgB',
  'prod_kpnNwA1P8awmXB'
];

<Box onClick={() => navigate(`/${id[1]}/${comboproductsids[(index + 1) % comboproductsids.length]}`)}
```

With the modulo, it will return `0` everytime you reache your array's limit

Comment: but i need to be replacing product_id in there: http://localhost:3000/combo/prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD, where prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD is the product_id

Comment: And ? you have a global variable containing all your product's list right (my `products`) ? so you can move throught it with an incrementor variable (my `i`), so using the modulo should be fine no ? I can't help you more with so few codes... add more like "how do you change your product" ? please show Button's code

Comment: <Box onClick={()=>{prevProduct()}} component={Link} to={`/`} sx={{padding:"15px", cursor:"pointer"}}>&#8249; Prev |</Box>  So instead of {`/`}  i need to put localhost:3000/combo/prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD, where prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD can be replaced with the values from that array of product-id. So when clicked - next product will open

Comment: I excepted you update your original post in order to use readable formatage, but fine, how do you know `prevProduct()` value ? i guess you have a `nextProduct()` function as well ?

Comment: yep, Prev and Next buttons. Whatever i do it just adds new route to existing one. So i need to figure how i can just change last element of the route (product_id). I hope u get what i mean.  So this part stays the same - localhost:3000/combo/   But product ids are changing

Comment: Yeah i understood your goal, but i don't understand "how" you do it at the moment, can you provide a well formated version of `nextProduct()`'s code in your original question ?

Comment: i dont think it will help. Firstly i click on the VIEW button to open 1 product which belongs to Combo group.  <Button sx={viewButton} component={Link} to={`./${product.id}`}> VIIEW </Button> Once inside this product- i added buttons Prev and Next to move through the other 6 products i have inside Combo category. Does it make sense?  so from  localhost:3000/combo i initially go to localhost:3000/combo/prod_G6kVw7pV6Oo2eD but then i need to move from one product to another. When i say move i mean i need to be opening links. localhost:3000/combo/product2 or localhost:3000/combo/product3

Comment: it make sens, but please your code is illisible, format it in your original message (the one above all theses comments), and just copy paste the true function, u talked about `${product.id}` but what is product ? an object ? contained in an array ? don't reply HERE but in your original post, nobody can help you without this effort of you

Comment: i posted my solution above. pls have a look

Comment: Okay, crystal clear now. you just have to use my solution

Comment: I edited my solution, so please mark your question as "resolved" or delete your topic

Comment: yep code makes sense but something is still missing. I can see URL are changing, showing new product id. However page isnt refreshing. Index is changing to 0 once i move forward till the last product. but when i go back it doesnt stop and navigates to http://localhost:3000/combo/undefined     Gonna look for the missing part now

Comment: if it show you `/combo/undefined` then it must be because `(index + 1) % comboproductsids.length` is greater than `comboproductsids.length`, can you try `console.log()` it ?

Comment: just checked. it allows index to become -1. its not changing to 0. Whilst when i increment it wont going beyond 6. from 6 goes to 0.  But whats more concerning is that i can see that product URL is changing. But i am sill on the same page. Need to force rerender maybe. When i manually refresh the page it shows correct product, matching ID

Comment: ok i fixed -1 issue   === (index<1?1:index)

Comment: Just need to fix page loading issue now

Comment: It's a react's life cycle issue, so you have 2 solution:
- the good one: reworking all of your architecture
- the bad one: adding a mere `window.location.reload();` to force the current page's reload

Comment: yeah i get it. my logic isnt the best there. So i just need to figure how online shops handle it. couldnt find any good examples. Do u know any? I am building an eshop. using Commerce js.

Comment: fixed it. added 2nd function to onClick (1st one is navigate). Added this one: const refreshPage = () => {
    navigate(0);
    console.log('check');
}

Answer (score 0):

found solution!

```
<Box onClick={()=>navigate(`/${id[1]}/${comboproductsids[index+1]}`)}
```

where  `const id = window.location.pathname.split("/"); const indexid = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]; const index = comboproductsids.indexOf(indexid)`

now just need to figure how to go back first product once i reach last product